# Geography-column with LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-To-Sql , and need to compute the column that is of geography data type.  I keep searching and searching and finding answers that say this is not possible.  All these answers are old , I know that it is now possible I just can not remember how to do it.

Comment: Switch to Entity Framework - it supports the spatial data types in SQL Server. Linq-to-SQL is dead - no more development of new features to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq-to-Sql is officially a *legacy* ORM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178359.aspx#orm.

> LINQ to SQL is a legacy ORM that Microsoft provides.

Also

> Microsoft is investing minimal efforts to enhance it

Meaning: spatial data types will never be supported by Linq to Sql. That's why the old answers still apply and will always apply. Move to Entity Framework 5 or higher for an ORM with spatial data support.

Comment: that is not at all the answer I wanted to hear... is the last straw though in my decision to switch to Entity Framework

Comment: Good luck with your decision! You won't regret it. Fortunately the basic architecture of both is pretty similar: a context with sets. You may have to rewrite some queries, as LINQ-to-SQL was more forgiving in mixing-in LINQ to objects.